# How to find file that is missing a required string?

Tags: macos, command-line

On my OS X command line, I would like to find all files ending in .per that are missing the string 'connection_id'.

How do I go about doing this. Finding the files that have a given string is easy but am not sure how to do this if the string is missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.per' \! -exec grep -q 'connection_id' {} \; -print
```

Comment: Thank you Ignacio. This isn't working for me. When I execute it, nothing happens. There are about 100 files that are max 1k that should take a couple of seconds to work through but when executed, the prompt isn't returned and no info is shown.

Comment: @Eric: Had a small bug. Should be fine now.