# How to find file that is missing a required string in eclipse/windows?

Tags: windows, eclipse

Is there a tool that can help me flag or list all the files (usually code files like java, xml, sql, etc) in a directory, which do not contain a particular string within the code.

For Ex: I need a list of all the files in my project that do not contain the word "author" (the text could be arbitrary).

I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231446/how-to-find-file-that-is-missing-a-required-string), but it is for the OS-X and not for Windows/eclipse platform.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to make a copy of the tree, find all the files which contain the word, and delete them. The remaining files are the ones which don't contain the word.

Comment: That's an interesting way of solving the issue, but I have to deal with a real time project, which could take up roughly about 200-300 MB. Although I could replicate the project to identify, I was hoping to see if there is an out-of-box tool that helps me do this task.
If there isn't one, I would certainly go with the suggested approach. Thank you!